# How is Gitlab's "project workspace" defined and propagated between jobs?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Gitlab's documentation often mentions a "project workspace" without actually defining its construction and functionality. One example is from the [chapter about Git strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pipelines/settings.html#git-strategy) which just plain tells the user "Using git fetch which is faster as it re-uses the project workspace (falling back to clone if it doesn't exist)." and doesn't define the way of reusage in any way.

I would like to understand how it's created, how it's tranferred between jobs and how this impacts jobs running in a Docker executor. Is there some kind of information about this apart from the source code? Have I missed some crucial part of the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no concept of a GitLab-specific workspace as far as I know. Perhaps it might be worth suggesting a change in that documentation page (everyone can submit a merge request using the links at the bottom of each docs page).

I would say workspace in that concepts simply refers to either the parent directory under which you clone a Git repository, or the repository's own directory. [This other document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/university/training/topics/getting_started.html#instantiate-workflow-with-clone) provides some more context.

Answer (score 0):

Since [GitLab 16.0 (May 2023)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/05/22/gitlab-16-0-released/#remote-development-workspaces-available-in-beta-for-public-projects), there is a notion of "project workspace" (for GitLab Premium or Ultimate only)

> ### Remote development workspaces available in Beta for public projects
>
> Stop spending hours, or even days, troubleshooting your local development environment and interpreting inscrutable package installation errors. Now you can define a consistent, stable, and secure development environment in code and use it to create on-demand, remote development workspaces.
>
> These workspaces serve as personal, ephemeral development environments in the cloud. By eliminating the need for a local development environment, you can focus more on your code and less on your dependencies. Accelerate the process of onboarding to a new project and get up and running in minutes instead of days.
>
> After the GitLab Agent for Kubernetes is configured and the dependencies are installed in your self-hosted cluster or cloud platform of choice, you can define your development environment in a `.devfile.yaml` file and store it in a public project.
> Then, you and any other developers with access to the agent can create a workspace based on the `.devfile.yaml` file and edit directly in the embedded Web IDE. You’ll have full terminal access to the container, allowing you to work more efficiently.
> When you’re done, or if something goes wrong, you can shut down the workspace and start a fresh, new workspace for your next development task.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/workspace/index.html) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10122).

And:

See [GitLab 16.4](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/09/22/gitlab-16-4-released/#create-workspaces-for-private-projects) (September 2023)

> ### Create workspaces for private projects

Create workspaces for private projects

> Previously, it was not possible to [create a workspace](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/workspace/configuration.html#set-up-a-workspace) for a private project. To clone a private project, you could only authenticate yourself after you created the workspace.
>
> With GitLab 16.4, you can create a workspace for any public or private project. When you create a workspace, you get a personal access token to use with the workspace. With this token, you can clone private projects and perform Git operations without any additional configuration or authentication.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_4/create-workspace-from-private-repo.png -- Create workspaces for private projects]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/workspace/#personal-access-token) and [Epic](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10882).

---

[GitLab 16.8](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2024/01/18/gitlab-16-8-released/#workspaces-are-now-generally-available) (January 2024) adds (again, for GitLab Premium or Ultimate only)

> ### Workspaces are now generally available
>
> We’re thrilled to share that workspaces are now generally available and ready to improve your developer efficiency!
>
> By creating secure, on-demand remote development environments, you can reduce the time you spend managing dependencies and onboarding new developers and focus on delivering value faster. With our platform-agnostic approach, you can use your existing cloud infrastructure to host your workspaces and keep your data private and secure.
>
> Since their introduction in GitLab 16.0, workspaces have received improvements to error handling and reconciliation, support for private projects and SSH connections, additional configuration options, and a new administrator interface. These improvements mean that workspaces are now more flexible, more resilient, and more easily managed at scale.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_8/workspaces-ga.png -- Workspaces are now generally available]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/workspace/) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/groups/gitlab-org/-/epics/10372).